ERROR : rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
After using the Livox laser simulation plugin, I've encountered issues with TF generation.
['dot', '-Tdot', '/tmp/tmp5kxx5zei'] return code: 1

stdout, stderr:
 b''
b"Error: /tmp/tmp5kxx5zei: syntax error in line 6 near ':'\n"

PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_tf_tree/RosTfTree#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 121, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 131, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_tf_graph()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 143, in _refresh_tf_graph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 150, in _generate_dotcode
    return self.dotcode_generator.generate_dotcode(dotcode_factory=self.dotcode_factory,
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/dotcode_tf.py", line 98, in generate_dotcode
    self.dotcode = self.dotcode_factory.create_dot(self.graph)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/pydotfactory.py", line 175, in create_dot
    dot = graph.create_dot()
  File "/home/cho/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1662, in new_method
    return self.create(
  File "/home/cho/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1885, in create
    assert p.returncode == 0, p.returncode
AssertionError: 1

The rqt_tf_tree is not being generated properly.
My suspicion is that there might be issues with the Python library version.
Is there a solution to this?
